# preg_replace function not functioning on PHP variables containing doublequotes(")

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, double-quotes

$words is creat"ive

$string is Recreat"ive

both are obtained from database through result sets

```
function highlightWords($string,$words) {
           $string = preg_replace("/$words/i", "<font style=\"background-color:yellow;\">$0</font>",$string); //To highlight $words in $string
}
```

The preg_replace function is not working for the above code. But it works if the code is

```
function highlightWords() {

    $words='creat"ive';
    $string='Recreat"ive'

    $string = preg_replace("/$words/i", "<font style=\"background-color:yellow;\">$0</font>",$string);
}
```

Comment: Both the suggestions didnt work. Adding on.... I got the result for substr($words,6) as quot;ive

Comment: passing $string by value or returning the preg_replace o/p didnt work.

Comment: Atlast it worked.
`code`
$words=str_replace('&quot;','"',$words);
  $words=str_replace('&amp;','&',$words);
  $words=str_replace('&#039;',"'",$words);
  $words=str_replace('&lt;','<',$words);
  $words=str_replace('&gt;','>',$words);
  
  $string=preg_replace('/'.$words.'/i', "<font style=\"background-color:yellow;\">$0</font>",$string);
`code`

Answer (score 1):

Use [preg_quote()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) on your pattern (ie $words)

Comment: Both the suggestions didnt work. Adding on.... I got the result for substr($words,6) as quot;ive

Answer (score 1):

first of all,  `$new_words` doesn't exist. i think you meant `$newwords` second, your function isn't doing anything to `$string` outside of the function because it is local to the function. pass it in by reference if you want to modify it.

```
function highlightWords(&$string,$words) {
    $newwords="background color changed words";
    $string = preg_replace("/$words/i", "<font style=\"background-color:yellow;\">$newwords</font>",$string); //To highlight $words in $string
}
```

it may be better to just pass `$string` in by value and simply `return` the new value:

```
function highlightWords($string,$words) {
    $newwords="background color changed words";
    return preg_replace("/$words/i", "<font style=\"background-color:yellow;\">$newwords</font>",$string); //To highlight $words in $string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
preg_replace('/'.$words.'/i',  "<font style=\"background-co...
```

Comment: Both the suggestions didnt work. Adding on.... I got the result for substr($words,6) as quot;ive